# RequiredFieldValidator - how to get rid of the default red font color

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, validation

I can't seems to change the default color of the required field validator.  In the source it is:

```
<span class="required">*</span>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valReq_txtTracks" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtTracks"
    Display="Dynamic" />
```

Here's what I have in my .skin file:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
    CssClass="error-text"
    ErrorMessage="required" />
```

In the rendered source I see:

```
<span class="required">*</span>
<span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_valReq_txtTracks" class="error-text" style="color:Red;display:none;">required</span>
```

Notice the "style=color:Red;".  That needs to go.  I can't override it with a css-class because it's inline CSS.  What should I do?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a [RequiredFieldValidator.ForeColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.forecolor.aspx) property you can set to control the color. Note that if you want to set the color in CSS, then you need to set ForeColor="" to clear it on the control.

Comment: I added ForeColor="" to the .skin file and that did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I know this an old thread, but I ran into this another day. It's kind of odd that setting style sheet does not override the text color of the validator. In my case, I had a whole bunch of different validators and extended validators that I wanted to override text color for, so instead of a theme and skin file, I created custom control adapter that handles rendering of BaseValidator control. Inside the rendering method, I just set `ForeColor = Color.Empty`. Hopefully this helps other people who ran into this situation and want to override text color for all kind of validators (required field, regular expression, compare,...).

Comment: Thanks for your additional answer on this question. I knew that I needed to clear the ForeColor, but the accepted answer of setting it to "" didn't account for the fact that ForeColor is of type System.Drawing.Color now.

Comment: It's actually always been System.Drawing.Color, but if you're setting it on the ASPX page you can use an empty string. In code-behind, Color.Empty is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to add style attribute with empty string in the skin file:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
    CssClass="error-text"
    style=""
    ErrorMessage="required" />
```

Comment: mohammedn, "style" attribute is not present in RequiredFieldValidator !

Answer (score 1):

I read somewhere to use the !important tag in your css class to override the inline css...

Comment: That worked too, but I wanted the color style removed by the asp.net engine, not css inheritance.  Thanks though!

Answer (score -2):

Using `!important` seems to work fine in Firefox and IE, but for some reason not in Google Chrome... no biggie though, Chrome's share is still very low.

```
.form_error
{
    font: bold 15px arial black,arial,verdana,helvetica !important; 
    color: #ff0000 !important;
}
```